"Whether we buy a new car is still to be decided." — Can we use "if" instead of "whether"?
I know sometimes we can replace "whether" with "if" and sometimes we can't.
In this thread, I'm interested in the particular occasion when "whether" stands at the beginning of sentences.
Can we use "if" instead of "whether" in this case?
wordreference.com:
(1a) Whether we buy a new car is still to be decided.
(2a) Whether we are going to buy a new car is no business of yours.
wordreference.com:
(3a) Whether they reach the goal or not depends partly on luck.
collinsdictionary.com:
(4a) Whether we go or whether we stay, the result is the same.
(5a) Whether it turns out to be a good idea or a bad idea, we'll find out.
my variants:
(1b) If we buy a new car is still to be decided.
(2b) If we are going to buy a new car is no business of yours.
(3b) If they reach the goal or not depends partly on luck.
(4b) If we go or if we stay, the result is the same.
(5b) If it turns out to be a good idea or a bad idea, we'll find out.
Are the b-variants correct?

1b and 2b are not grammatical. 3b is marginal.

I find 5a   quite odd with its combination of "find out" and "turns out".  The sentence really makes very little sense to me. Does it mean "We'll hear about it"? or "We'll learn if it's a good idea by trying it" ?

I hear these fairly often in casual speech but they may be a little less clear— or even seem ungrammatical— to other native speakers. So I would say they are grammatical, but should be avoided in formal writing.
Additionally, 4 and 5 can potentially have subtly different meanings after the replacement. Whether implies that the possibilities are all of the possibilities, but if doesn't guarantee that. So, for example, Whether it turns out to be a good idea or a bad idea, we'll find out. implies you will always find out. If it turns out to be a good idea or a bad idea, we'll find out. could leave open the possibility that you won't find out, if the idea turns out to be neither good nor bad. Context would usually make these sentences mean the same thing, however.

The short answer to your question is "probably not." By that I mean that you might be able to argue that some of 1b-5b are grammatical, but you'd be pushing it.
Use whether or whether or not.

What does "but you'd be pushing it" mean? Thanks.

Sorry about that. It means your argument would be very weak. If it proved your point, it would barely prove it. But it's just as likely to be defeated by a counter-argument.

I. If or whether:.
OP's query:

In this thread, I'm interested in the particular occasion when "whether" stands at the beginning of sentences.
Can we use "if" instead of "whether" in this case?

OP is right when he says:
Sometimes we can replace and sometimes not.
The meaning of "sometimes" is defined by the dictionary.
Ref. Merriam Webster dictionary

If and whether are often interchangeable, but have distinct uses.
For clarity, it is best to use whether in reference to a choice or alternatives ("we're going whether it rains or not")
and if when establishing a condition ("we will go if it doesn't rain").

II. Comments on each individual sentences:.
OP has selected sentences where "whether" is the better choice. I have given my comments in bold and italics:

(1a) Whether we buy a new car is still to be decided.
(1b) If we buy a new car is still to be decided.
(In sentence 1a, the phrase "whether we buy a new car" presents a clear choice between two options: buying or not buying.
In sentence 1b, "If we buy a new car, is still to be decided," the word "if" introduces a condition. The sentence lacks clarity and there is no connection  with the other part "is still to be decided")
.
(2a) Whether we are going to buy a new car is no business of yours.
(2b) If we are going to buy a new car is no business of yours.
(In 2a - the two choices are clear - "going to buy or not going to buy". The sentence is concise.
In 2b - we have to rephrase to make the meaning clear:
(2b) If we are going to buy a new car or not going to buy is no business of yours.
It makes the sentence clumsy so using "whether" is a better choice..
.
(3a) Whether they reach the goal or not depends partly on luck.
(3b) If they reach the goal or not depends partly on luck.
(In this sentence we can use either "if" or "whether" but the latter is a better choice.).
.
(4a) Whether we go or whether we stay, the result is the same.
(4b) If we go or if we stay, the result is the same.
(In this sentence both the options are correct but "whether" is a better choice.).
.
(5a) Whether it turns out to be a good idea or a bad idea, we'll find out.
(5b) If it turns out to be a good idea or a bad idea, we'll find out.
(In this sentence both the options are correct but "whether" is a better choice.)

